# How to put image with glide downloader to listview

Tags: java, android, android-glide

i'm trying to add glide downloaded image to list view.
When clicking on image in the recycler view, it should be added to another view as image downloaded with glode.
For now , the app crashes on click on the recycler view item with error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

There is my code:

```
private RecyclerView mRVLights;
    private ArrayList<Light> mLightsArray = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<RequestBuilder<Drawable>> mLightsHistory = new ArrayList<RequestBuilder<Drawable>>();
    private LightsAdapter mLightsAdapter;
    private ListView mHistoryListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<RequestBuilder<Drawable>> adapter;
```

onClickRecyclerViewItem:

```
RequestBuilder<Drawable> image = Glide.with(getContext())
                            .load(mLightsArray.get(position).getLampImageUrl())
                            .override(60, 60);

                    mLightsHistory.add(0, image);
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RequestBuilder<Drawable>>(getContext(), R.layout.history_item_view, mLightsHistory);
                    mHistoryListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

XML:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/historyLightIMG"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/no_accessibility" />
```

Comment: You'd have to create a custom adapter, not a plain ArrayAdapter, which only can load to a TextView

Comment: You could create an imageview in code behind for each image then by Glide add the image to it and finally add each imageview to your linearlayout (that is in xml) total process by a loop.This process automatically arranges your images in your layout and I think is not necessary  to use a listview.